# C++ LNK1561 error (when main() is included)

Tags: c++, lnk

For some reason, even though I have a main() function defined, I am receiving a LNK1561 error.

My search.h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

namespace standard{
class Search
{
public:
    bool sequential_find(int num);
    bool recursive_binary_find(int num);
    bool iterative_binary_find(int num);

    void init_array();
    void init_sorted_array();
    void set_seed(int seed);
    int getSize();

    bool binSearch(int d, int low, int high);

    // this is just for practice and debugging.
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Search& s)
    {
        // put the code in here.
    }

    Search(int size,int seed=0);
    ~Search();

private:

    int size;
    int* array;
    static int* data;
};
}
```

And my search.cpp file:

```
#include "Search.h"

    using namespace std;

    namespace standard{

        int main()
        {
            return 0;
        }

    //  Search::Search(int size,int seed=0)
    //  {
    //      
    //  }

        bool Search::sequential_find(int num)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<getSize(); i++)
            {
                if(data[i] == num)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


        bool Search::recursive_binary_find(int num)
        {
            int high = getSize()-1;
            int low = 0;
            return binSearch(num, low, high);
        }

        bool Search::binSearch(int d, int low, int high)
        {
            if (low > high)
                return false;
            int mid = (high+low)/2;
            if (d == data[mid])
                return true;
            if (d < data[mid])
                return binSearch(d, low, mid-1);
            else
                return binSearch(d, mid+1, high);
        }

        bool Search::iterative_binary_find(int num)
        {
            int high = getSize()-1;
            int low = 0;
            while (low <= high)
            {
                int mid = (high+low)/2;
                if (num == data[mid])
                    return true;
                else if (num < data[mid])
                    high = mid-1;
                else if (num > data[mid])
                    low = mid+1;
            }
            return false;
        }

        void Search::init_array()
        {

        }
        void Search::init_sorted_array()
        {

        }
        void Search::set_seed(int seed)
        {

        }
        int Search::getSize()
        {
            return size;
        }
    }
```

Obviously I haven't done anything substantial in my main function, I am working on just getting it to compile at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put your `main()` function in the `standard` namespace. That's not the entry point of your program. The entry point of your program should be in the global namespace.

Per paragraph 3.6.1/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> A program shall contain a **global** function called `main`, which is the designated start of the program. It
>   is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main
>   function.

To fix the problem, just move your `main()` to the global namespace. Also notice, that `return 0` is not necessary. Flowing off the end of `main()` is equivalent to returning 0.

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed that issue, and opened up plenty of others that I can now take on.

Answer (score 1):

You put `main` inside your own namespace `standard`, which makes it a function belongs to your namespace, not a global function which `main` should be anymore.

For C++ standard 3.6.1:

> A program shall **contain a global function called main**, which is the designated start of the program. It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main function. [...]